# How to get data from database without page reload with ajax using laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am working on simple private chat application ,when i send message to selected user. so message is sending perfectly but user receive message on page reload How to get data from database without page reload with ajax using laravel ?.Does Anybody have an idea ? How to do this please help me thanks.

**Controller**

```
           public function chataction(REQUEST $request)
           {
           $this->validate($request,
           [
           'message' => 'required', 
           ]);
            $chat_message = $request->get('message');
            $from_user_id=Auth::user()->id;
            $to_user_id =$request->get('myid');
            $user = Auth::user();
            $response = $user->Chats()->create([             
            'chat_message'=>  $chat_message,
            'from_user_id' => $from_user_id,
            'to_user_id'  => $to_user_id,
             ]);    
             $response = array(
             'status' => 'success',
             'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
              );
              return Response::json($response);  
              }






          public function chat($id)
          {
          $single_chat = User::with('Chats')->where('id',$id)->first();   
          $user_record_msg = User::with('Chat')->where('id',$id)->first();          
          return view('single_chat',compact('single_chat','user_record_msg'));
          }
```

**html view**

```
          // this loop used for from user message
         @foreach($user_record_msg->chat as $user_record_msgs)

          <div class="direct-chat-msg right">
          <div class="direct-chat-infos clearfix">
          <span class="direct-chat-name float-right"></span>
          <h6 class="direct-chat-timestamp float-left">{{$user_record_msgs->message_time}} 
          </h6>
          </div>
          <img class="direct-chat-img" src="{{url('public/assets/dist/img/user1- 
           128x128.jpg')}}" alt="message user image">
           <div class="direct-chat-text">
          {{$user_record_msgs->chat_message}}
           </div>
           </div>
           @endforeach


       // this loop used for to user message
        <!-- Message. Default to the left -->   
        @foreach($single_chat->chats as $single_chats)
        <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
        <div class="direct-chat-infos clearfix">
        <span class="direct-chat-name float-left">{{$single_chat->name}} </span>
        <h6 class="direct-chat-timestamp float-right">{{$single_chats->message_time}}</h6>
        </div>
        <!-- /.direct-chat-infos -->
        <img class="direct-chat-img" src="{{url('public/assets/dist/img/user1- 
        128x128.jpg')}}" alt="message user image">
         <!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
         <div class="direct-chat-text">
         {{$single_chats->chat_message}}
         </div>
         <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
         @endforeach
```

**Ajax**

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnsubmit").click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var form_data = $("#myform").serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"{{ route('chat.action') }}",
            data: form_data,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
            setInterval('location.reload()', 1000); 
            }
            });
            });
            });
            </script>
```

**Route**

```
        Route::get('/chat/{id}','HomeController@chat');
        Route::post('chat/action','HomeController@chataction')->name('chat.action');
```

Comment: show your `chataction()` function

Comment: please check chataction() function i have updated on top thanks.

Comment: you are expecting real time chat ? did u try with - https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel

Comment: no Actully i have seen this but my answer is not here .

Comment: To make a chat app you shouldn't use ajax. Best for a custom chat app is to use Vue. You can find many tutorials on the internet. If you are not comfortable with using Vue then Laravel Echo and Pusher would be your best option.
Here is a link: https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel